# How to add conditional logic in sightly code for an HTML attribute

Tags: aem, sightly

I tried searching but somehow i cannot get my way around thinking what do i need to add dynamic tags inside html element using sightly code.
Not sure if this is good practice or not, but wanted to ask.
Now i know how to apply cssclass to class attribute in an href. But what if i want to inject the entire attribute "class='one'" in an href how do i do that?

Can this be done. I know I could do something like

```
<a href="${properties['jcr:titleurl']}" class="${properties.openinnewwindow ? 'nonunderline' : ''}"> <h3>${properties['jcr:title']}</h3></a>
```

but i want to do this,

```
<div class="col-md-12">       
<a href="${properties['jcr:titleurl']}"  data-sly-test="${properties.openinnewwindow ? 'class=one' : class='two'}"> <h3>${properties['jcr:title']}</h3></a>
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you are looking to do in your code.  Maybe a  bit of an explanation of the context of the code as well.

Comment: Hi ,Yes, I am trying to inject class tag attribute with assignment in to the code using sightly. As mentioned before I am aware of how to assign class to a variable like class="${sightly code}", but what i want to do instead is assign the whole "class = one" in the href tag. This is important as sometimes you might not need the class attribute.
E.g if some of the html might have a class attribute with them and some might not.

I guess i am not following how would data-sly tag work inside the Html element. 
Let me know if you need more clarity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `data-sly-test` to determine whether to keep or remove the element, so it's not what you're looking for.

You mentioned that you don't want the class attribute if the variable is null or blank. Your provided code with the ternary operator will do just that.

```
<a href="#" class="${properties.openinnewwindow ? 'nonunderline' : ''}">link</a>
```

Sightly is very much like JavaScript in the concept of truthy/falsey. In your example if `openinnewwindow` is truthy (true, not null, or not undefined, etc...), the class attribute will be equal to `nonunderline`. If `openinnewwindow` is falsey, the class attribute will not appear in the rendered HTML.

Another way to write this code would be with the logical `&&` operator. This syntax is what you're asking for:

```
<a href="#" class="${properties.openinnewwindow && 'nonunderline'}">link</a>
```

See the [Sightly specification](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/sightly-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md) for more information.